# Meaning of draw

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of draw used in the following sentence

> Who **drew** the first prize?

Does it mean **to pull**, but this meaning is a bit awkward in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw) gives as sense 8 b of "draw"

> to receive or take at random
>
> > drew a winning number

This sense arises from the form of lottery whre tokes of some sort are mixed in a jar, box or other receptacle, and the winning token(s) are **drawn** out of the receptacle as a way of choosing them at random. So it is ultimately derived from the sense meaning "pull"  but via a metaphor.